# Segmentation fault after swap context

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why do I get segmentation fault when executing the following piece of code? I noticed that if I declare a second stack ( char s2[10000]; and init_context2(&unew2, s2, 10000);) everything works fine. But I can't understand why two stacks are required. Is it possible to use only one, if yes how?

output:
before context init
before context swap
Message
Message2
Segmentation fault

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>    
ucontext_t uold, unew, unew2;
char s1[10000];

static void message()
{
    puts("Message");
}

static void message2()
{
    puts("Message2");
}

void init_context(ucontext_t * uc, void* stack, size_t stack_size)
{
    //puts("Inside init context");
    getcontext(uc);
    uc->uc_link = &uold;
    uc->uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
    uc->uc_stack.ss_size = stack_size;
    uc->uc_stack.ss_flags = 0;
    makecontext(uc, message, 0);
}

void init_context2(ucontext_t * uc, void* stack, size_t stack_size)
{
    //puts("Inside init context 2");
    getcontext(uc);
    uc->uc_link = &uold;
    uc->uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
    uc->uc_stack.ss_size = stack_size;
    uc->uc_stack.ss_flags = 0;
    makecontext(uc, message2, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        puts("before context init");
        init_context(&unew, s1, 10000);
    init_context2(&unew2, s1, 10000);
    puts("before context swap");
    swapcontext(&uold, &unew);
    swapcontext(&uold, &unew2);
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Have you taken any steps to debug your code?

Comment: So s1 is your stack ? And you're sharing the stack between 2 different contexts ? That'll mean they wreck havoc on eachother. Your stack is also 10k, which might be too small, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: I tried to use gdb, it's the first time I use it so the only info I can get is
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000606640 in uold ()
Yes s1 is my stack, but why there should be a problem using the same stack? I have changed s1 to ten times bigger but still the same

Comment: probably problem is in other parts of code which you haven't shown

Comment: the code is as is. I don't include any custom functions. Sorry but I don't get exactly what you are saying

Comment: ok never mind-i thought some of the methods mentioned in the code were custom

Comment: ok no problem, if there is any unclear part I shall fix it

Comment: *"the code is as is"* except you haven't told us what `ucontext_t` is.

Comment: it is defined in <ucontext.h>. I just added the include and define statements

Comment: Just curious: why are you using these functions in the first place?  i.e. instead of pthread?

Comment: @BrianMcFarland I wrote this code to reproduce an error I get in another program. The initial program is a small os. At the moment no preemption is taking place. Each time I want to execute a new task I call Exec(task, argl, args). In the exec function takes place the context creation and initialization and after the storage in process control table. After the scheduler executes the processes swapping the saved contexts. But after swapping I get segmentation fault like here.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland So in this code the init_contex - 2 are like the exec (contexts are stored), the two swapcontexts are like scheduler (contexts are loaded and executed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are reusing the stack simultaneously for both contexts; that is, while both contexts are valid. `makecontext` initializes the stack with something (not sure exactly what, but possibly a return address that links back to the previous context), and thus one clobbers the other.

Simple moving your call to `init_context2()` to after the first context has run makes the program work:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    puts("before context init");
    init_context(&unew, s1, 10000);
    puts("before context swap");
    swapcontext(&uold, &unew);
    init_context2(&unew2, s1, 10000);
    swapcontext(&uold, &unew2);
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, except from solving the problem takes me one step closer in understanding the contextes. As I commented in the initial question : I wrote this code to reproduce an error I get in another program. The initial program is a small os. At the moment no preemption is taking place. Each time I want to execute a new task I call Exec(task, argl, args). In the exec function takes place the context creation and initialization and the storage in process control table.

Comment: After the scheduler executes the processes swapping the saved contexts. But after swapping I get segmentation fault like here. So in this code the init_contex - 2 are like the exec (contexts are stored), the two swapcontexts are like scheduler (contexts are loaded and executed)

Comment: So it is possible two init_context to take place together and after two swapcontext. Do I have to do something more than storing the initialized context in the process control block?

Comment: Anyway, I found the problem. The uc_link in each context should point to the parent context otherwise segmentation fault was taking place. Thanks!